# how to trigger scope watch in directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am trying to trigger my directive code with a scopewatcher:

```
var gMaps = function($timeout, $q, GeoCoder, mockdataService) {
      return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        template: '<div class="gmaps"></div>',
        replace: true,
        link: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {

          $scope.watch(scope.lat, function() {...
```

When I change the lat property on the form it does not trigger the function on the directive?

[plnkr link](http://plnkr.co/edit/c0Y7RJFWhWAu89czX2OW?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You just have the `$` on the wrong part. `$watch` is a method attached to the variable you named `scope`. Just use `scope.$watch` instead of `$scope.watch`.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to use `scope.$watch(...)` instead of `$scope.watch(...)` becuse you have `scope` (not `$scope`) as argument in your `link` function. You have also missed `$` before `watch`

You should also use $watch like this

```
scope.$watch('lat',function(newVal, oldVal){
   //this will watch scope.lat
});
```

or

```
scope.$watch(function(){
   return scope.lat
},
function(newVal, oldVal){
  //this function will be fired everytime first function return other value than before
});
```